# Getting value of only 1 random row and set the values to a class

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, session, servlets

I've been trying to set the value of a random row from my table but it kept on giving me a null value when I try to retrieve it from my servlet.

This is my codes to retrieve the random row and setting the values to my class. sq is the name of the table.

```
public Question getQuestion() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Getting the questions");

    Question question = null;
    try{
        String selectStatement = "select * from sq order by rand() limit 1";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            Question myquestion = new Question();
            myquestion.setQid(rs.getInt("QID"));
            myquestion.setQuestion(rs.getString("question"));
            //System.out.println(rs.getString("question"));
            System.out.println(myquestion.getQuestion());
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new Exception("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return question;
}
```

It prints out the question here but it gives me a null value in my servlet.

```
try{
            Database myDatabase = new Database();
            Question question = myDatabase.getQuestion();
            if(question != null){
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("secquestion", question);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("SecQn.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }else{
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

It prints out ERROR which means question's value is null when I have already set the value previously. How do I set the value correctly? Or is there anything wrong with my codes?

---

SOLVED THE ERROR. THIS IS THE LATEST OF THE UPDATED CODES.

```
public Question getQuestion() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Getting the questions");

    Question question = null;
    try{
        String selectStatement = "select * from sq order by rand() limit 1";
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectStatement);
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            question = new Question();
            question.setQid(rs.getInt("QID"));
            question.setQuestion(rs.getString("question"));
            System.out.println(question.getQuestion());
        }       
    }catch(Exception ex){
        throw new Exception("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return question;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getQuestion()` method you are returning question but you never assigned it any value.
You should either return `myquestion` , or assign  before returning.

```
question = myquestion ;
```